# Hosting NativeViewer files in own storage

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I have the Autodesk Forge NativeViewer up and running but now want to download the translated files and store in my own storage account, rather than AWS, and serve up the files to the viewer from there.

Setting the environment setting for the Viewer to 'Local' and then calling the loadModel function passing in the URL to the hosted svf file does make the viewer resolve the files from my own storage account but I have two issues:

1. If an already URL encoded SAS token is appended to the URL it is being encoded again causing issues with special characters.
2. I am unable to override XHR calls as they are made from within a Web Workers.

Is there an object available which I can override to set headers or manipulate the HTTP calls for loading the viewer assets? The web worker code looks to be dynamically loaded every time and Ithere does not appear to be any objects off of the global LMV object instance which I can override to give me access to HTTP headers etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the LMV object exposes an instance of 'endpoint' which exposes the HTTP_HEADERS collection that is used when each derivative is loaded. By adding an Authorisation header to this collection, I'm able to load derivatives from a local storage account.

```
LMV.endpoint.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKENVALUE'
};
```